# How do I return the current domain of my project in javascript and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some javascript that requires a specific URL to call an ASP.NET web service.
When I run the application locally, the url is something like:

```
http://localhost:123456/ProjectName/Default.aspx
```

But when I upload the application, the domain will change to:

```
http://myDomain.com/Default.aspx
```

What's the best way to capture the current URL path and pass it in as a variable to my javascript? Here is my javascript:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#autoComplete").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "http://localhost:123456/ProjectName/Default.asmx/SkillsList", //CHANGE THE URL!!
                          //url: "http://myDomain.com/Default.asmx", //The other URL...
                            data: "{'like':'" + request.term + "'}",
                            datatype: "json",
                            async: true,
                            success: function(data) {
                                response(data.d);
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                            alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
    </script>
```

I'm using ASP.NET if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You should know your domain, what's the need to "detect it"? add a key to web.config and set localhost for DEV and yourdomain.com for production code if that's what you need.

Comment: Using the relative path doesn't work since AutoComplete.asmx is at the root level. If I put "/ProjectName/Default.asmx/SkillsList" it does work. However, when I upload the application, the path won't be the same. It won't be ProjectName anymore, it will be DomainName.com

Comment: `/ProjectName/Default..` etc is an absolute path in the sense that it stars from the root. You should do `../Whatever/` or `Directory/Whatever.asmx` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're writing out to the aspx page.  Given that, you should be able to just have ASP.Net tell you via something like

```
url: "<%= Request.ApplicationPath%>/Default.asmx/SkillsList"
```

Answer (score 4):

post to relative path

```
url: "/ProjectName/Default.asmx/SkillsList"
```